# calculate values from a field and insert them into custom fields when publishing or updating post

Tags: hooks, publish

I want to parse some information from an url when the post is published. So if I enter an URL into the Title field of a post, I want to execute a php script, that parses data from that URL and enters it into some custom fields. Is there a way to do that?

thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [**`save_post`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) hook, this is a hook that fires once a post has been saved. Below is an example addressing what you want to achieve:

```
function wpse253778_calculate_values( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type )
        return;

    $field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'FIELD_NAME', true ); //get field value

    $new_field_value = '';//calculate new field value

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'NEW_FIELD', $new_field_value );

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse253778_calculate_values', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, it works partially. So if I enter a new value into the field and hit publish/update nothing happens in the field, where the calculated value should be stored. When I hit publish again, it is getting filled up. So it seems, that the first field is read before any data is written to it.